# RE Pattern for finding sets in a string

Tags: python-3.7, python-re

I'm searching for the best pattern to use in `re.findall` to find all none-empty sets in my input string.
for example:

```
['{2}', '{5, 65, 75909}', '{26, 90, 4590984}']
```

is the desirable output for input string comes below:

```
'kka{2}343{}lds{5, 65, 75909}892,{26, 90, 4590984}'
```

I've surfed the net but didn't find anything; Does anybody know what is the best pattern?
And also, my attempts of using `(,\s)?` in patterns resulted in a list of 2-tuples containing only the last number of sets along with an empty string. How I get tuples containing empty strings? What sort of thing in a pattern can lead me to empty strings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't forget [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might help you, it looks for every set which has *number[s]* in it and extracts it.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("{\d+[, \d]*}")
string = "'kka{2}343{}lds{5, 65, 75909}892,{26, 90, 4590984}'"
print(pattern.findall(string))
```

The resuls  is `['{2}', '{5, 65, 75909}', '{26, 90, 4590984}']`

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: this can be done without any modules, too:

```py
instr = 'kka{2}343{}lds{5, 65, 75909}892,{26, 90, 4590984}'
pos = 0
output = []
while pos < len(instr):
    start, end = pos + instr[pos:].find("{"), pos + instr[pos:].find("}") # find positions of opening and closing bracket in the unprocessed part of the string
    pos = end + 1 # update pos so we don't process only the first couple of brackets each loop
    if start + 1 == end: # opening bracket { is directly before a closing bracket }, that means we have an empty set
        continue
    output.append(instr[start:end + 1])
print(output)
```